# tkinter - selecting values from Combobox resets the value of an another Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Combobox and a Listbox like this:

```py
cities = df[df.columns[0]].tolist()
city_frame = tk.Frame(root)
city_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
cities_var = tk.Variable()
cities_var.set(cities)
tk.Label(city_frame, text="Thành phố").grid(row=0, column=0)
selected_cities_lb = tk.Listbox(
    city_frame, height=20, listvariable=cities_var, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE
)
selected_cities_lb.grid(row=1, column=0)

plot_types = ['parallel coordinate', 'stacked bar chart', 'grouped bar chart']
plot_type_frame = tk.Frame(root)
plot_type_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.N)
plot_type_var = tk.StringVar()
plot_type_var.set(plot_types[0])
tk.Label(plot_type_frame, text="Loại biểu đồ").grid(row=0, column=0)
selected_plot_type_lb = ttk.Combobox(
    plot_type_frame, textvariable=plot_type_var, values=plot_types, state='readonly')
selected_plot_type_lb.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

There is one problem: when I selected any values from the Combobox, it unsets all checked values from the Listbox, which is very tedious. Any ideas what is going on here? Because to me they are completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: Both widgets need to have `exporteselection=False` added to them.  The default behavior is for the widget's selection to be tied to the system clipboard, which means that only one widget at a time can *have* a selection.

Answer (score 1):

adding `exportselection=False` solved this.